# Display stock OEM dialer within my app (and block back and HOME key press)

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Android app that has a dialer tab at the top of the screen. When user presses the tab, it should display the phone dialer.
I have a requirement that that the back button and HOME key presses should be dropped (user shouldn't be allowed to exit the app).

Which is the best way to display the dialer? Is it essential to create my own dialer for this app?
Or can I somehow run the stock OEM dialer within my activity? If this is possible, I believe the user can just press the back key or HOME button and exit out of my app.

Please suggest an approach.

Comment: sorry you can't block HOME button for security reasons.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia: I researched quite a bit on this and figured out that the only way to achieve this is to register the app as a launcher in the manifest file. User can press the HOME key and go to the home screen. This defeats the purpose of the app. The app idea is to limit the functionality of the user to just the dialer and contacts. Would really appreciate if you recommend a way to handle it.

Comment: @webgenius product requirements do not supersede the limitations of the platform. You cannot block/intercept the HOME button.